# how to embed YouTube video in iOS UITableViewCell

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I would like to embed YouTube videos in UITableViewCells of my iOS app.

first of all I config the youtube-ios-player package in my Podfile using this command:
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper"

then I create a custom cell and add a YTPlayerView on each cell.

when I ran my app I found that the tableview stuck.So is there a better way to embed YouTube videos to my app.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some research, I found a way that can make the tableview run fluently.

Try this url we will get a image:

[https://img.youtube.com/vi/\(videoId)/0.jpg](https://img.youtube.com/vi/%5C(videoId)/0.jpg)

I create a UIImageView on each cell.
When the user clicks on the cell, I call the playVideo() method.